# Can no longer share same window across multiple screens on Mavericks

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, external-display, osx-mavericks

(with Mountain Lion) I used to be able to drag a screen halfway between two monitors (in multi display) mode and view both respective components of that window on either screen. This allowed me, in the case of the Picasa app, to view a map of location pins on the big screen while I selected photos on my laptop. Is there any way to reactivate this lost feature?

Comment: See the answers to [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575106/macosx-maverick-10-9-how-do-i-stretch-a-window-across-both-of-my-dual-screens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking for the same solution myself. Will update you if I find it. 
J

ok. so System preferences. Mission Control. Uncheck "displays have separate spaces"
logout. Login. Viola!
Cheers. 
J